# Wait 3 seconds before function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I've looked at some solutions here, but none seem to be working.  Basically, I am using a hidden class.  I have written Javascript that strips the hidden class and adds the classes of "animated pulse" from animate.css.  How can I have it so that the JS doesn't go through with the function until 3 seconds after page load?

```
<style>

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#gallery {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}

</style>

... end head, start body ...

<h2 class="hidden" id="gallery">Testing 123 456 789 Testing</h2>

... skip to bottom ...

<!-- Code that is not working -->

<script>

$("document").ready(function() {
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
        $("gallery").removeClass("hidden").addClass("animated pulse");
    }, 3000));
});

</script>
```

Comment: remove the jQuery around the setTimeout.  Using .data() just sets the data- attribute in HTML elements

Answer (score 5):

what about

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#gallery").removeClass("hidden").addClass("animated pulse");
    }, 3000));
});
```

as always @A. Wolff mention  that you can use

```
$("#gallery").toggleClass("hidden animated pulse");
```

Comment: It should be `$(document)` not `$("document")` even both work but... ;)

Comment: I guess OP could use: `$("#gallery").toggleClass("hidden animated pulse");`

Comment: @A.Wolff what can i say? :) .. you are right I just supposed  that the OP problem is just use settimeout  with right way .. I updated my answer .. thanks a lot :) .. did you believe me when I said happy to see you here :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I have it so that the JS doesn't go through with the function until 3 seconds after page load?

The jQuery Way™ to delay some script execution is with [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) and [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue). Also note that you said "page load" not "document ready" there is a significant difference between the two. If you want images to be loaded, be sure to listen for `.load`.

```
// page load version
$(window).on('load', function () {

// document ready vresion
jQuery(function ($) {

    // rest of the function body remains the same:
    $('#gallery')
        .delay(3000)
        .queue(function (next) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('animated pulse');
            next();
        });
});
```